# How to change month view in bootstrap-datepicker when updateViewDate is false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I have an issue. I have set updateViewDate to false. The problem is that when I try to change date with code like this `$('#calendar').datepicker('setDate', '2019-12-20');` month view doesn't change, it still shows current (November) month. If updateViewDate is set to true when it works perfectly fine. How to fix this? Full code:

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    language: 'lt',
    autoclose: true,
    templates: {
        leftArrow: ' ',
        rightArrow: ' '
    },
    orientation: 'auto',
    updateViewDate: false,
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        if(enabledDates.hasOwnProperty(date.toLocaleDateString('lt-LT'))) {
            return {
                enabled: true, 
                classes: ((enabledDates[date.toLocaleDateString('lt-LT')] > 0 ? 'reservation-date' : 'full-reserved-date'))
            };
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    $('.free-times').html('');
    lastSelectedDate = e.format();

    $.get('/reservation/short-term/get-free-times', 
    { 
        selectedDate: lastSelectedDate, 
        premiseId: premiseId,
        userSelectedTimes: Object.keys(userSelectedTimes)
    }, function(data) {
        $('.free-times').html(data);
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
}).on('changeMonth', function(e) {
    var selectedDate = e.date.toLocaleDateString('lt-LT');

    $.get('{{ route('reservation.update-calendar') }}', 
    { 
        selectedDate: selectedDate, 
        premiseId: premiseId,
    }, function(data) {
        enabledDates = data;
        $('#calendar').datepicker('update');
        if(lastSelectedDate) {
            $('#calendar').datepicker('setDate', lastSelectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for help in advance!

P.S Tried `$('#calendar').datepicker('_setDate', lastSelectedDate, 'view');` it kind of works, but I want that after this function call changeMonth method would be called (Only if that month is different than current)